# Cómo centrar los valores en un histograma en matplotlib.?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

He buscado pero no consigo entender cómo centrar las barras del histograma con los números .

Tengo los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer un histograma de la segunda columna (columna B), para observar cual es la frecuencia de cada valor , por lo cual hago lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_raw = pd.read_excel('pr2.xlsx',header=None)

data_no_na=data_raw.dropna() # se eliminaron todos las filas vacias

data_ready = data_no_na.round(0).astype(int) #se llevaron los valores a datos typo enteros

plt.hist(data_ready[1],edgecolor ='black')
plt.xlabel('Optica de ONT',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Numeros de ONT con esa optica',fontsize=15)
#plt.xticks(range(12),range(12))
plt.show()
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedes observar los datos no están centrados en cada barra. Por ejemplo :

El -21 se repite 3 veces pero está en el borde de una barra no está en el centro de la barra, el número -24 está como queriendose salir.

Si te das cuenta en el código traté de centrar los valores con el método xticks pero lo puse como comentario porque no funciona.

Otra duda, en el eje Y me salen números decimales, sin embargo solo quiero que salgan enteros, cómo puedo hacer eso ?

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Debes utilizar el argumento `bins()` para alinear los `xticks`.

Para hacerlo más fácilmente, creamos un arreglo de `numpy` de un rango desde -29 hasta -19.

```
np.arange(-29,-19)
```

Esto nos creará el siguiente arreglo

```
array([-29, -28, -27, -26, -25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20])
```

Pero ya que deseas alinear al centro entonces restamos 0.5 a cada elemento del arreglo (Por ésta razón uso numpy, para que podamos restar 0.5 a todo el arreglo anterior fácilmente)

```
np.arange(-29,-19)-0.5
```

Esto altera el arreglo original y nos devuelve lo siguiente:

```
array([-29.5, -28.5, -27.5, -26.5, -25.5, -24.5, -23.5, -22.5, -21.5, -20.5])
```

Esto será el origen de las barras del histograma.

Luego utilizamos el método `xticks()` para definir las posiciones de cada uno de las marcas en el eje "X" y para eso utilizamos otra vez un rango de -29 a -19 ya que los datos que muestran van todos del -29 al -21. Tu intentaste con 12 y al ser valor positivo supongo que te generaba las marcas del 0 al 11,

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(-29,-19))
```

Juntando todo lo de los comentarios anteriores (Hice un archivo "sample2.csv" con los datos de la columna B, para la siguiente por favor ingresa tus datos como texto para que podamos copiarlos y utilizarlos):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')

plt.hist(df,edgecolor ='black', bins=np.arange(-29,-19)-0.5)
plt.xlabel('Optica de ONT',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Numeros de ONT con esa optica',fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(np.arange(-29,-19))
plt.show()
```

Esto devuelve:

[image: Gráfica]

**Edición:** Para evitar que el eje "Y" tenga números flotantes lo más fácil es crear un rango con los valores que vas a utilizar (Tal como se hizo con "X")

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,4))
```

Otra forma de hacerlo es obteniendo los valores de "Y" directamente de la gráfica y luego convertirlos a entero

```
yint = []
locs, labels = plt.yticks()
for each in locs:
    yint.append(int(each))
plt.yticks(yint)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Nunca hubiera podido resolver este problema sin tu ayuda. Estaba atascado allí. Una pregunta sino sería molestia, tampoco he dado : en el eje de las Y como eliminar esos números como float (0.5, 1.5) y ponerlos como enteros (1, 2 . . n)

Comment: Buen día, ya edité la respuesta y agregué lo de el eje "Y". Por favor ten en cuenta para futuras preguntas que solo debe haber una pregunta por publicación, eso ayuda a otros usuarios a encontrar la respuesta a preguntas similares más fácilmente.

Comment: @NIN, Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: Me has ayudado mucho.